# How to use path in Python webSockets package？

Tags: python, websocket

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro/tutorial1.html
I have read the official documentation for server, but what if I want to write a path

for example：

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost/my_path:8088") as websocket:
        await websocket.send("Hello world!")
        await websocket.recv()

asyncio.run(hello())
```

I tried the following but got an error

```
import asyncio

import websockets


async def handler(websocket):
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        print(message)


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost/my_path", 8088):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python_code/websocket-server/websocket_server-demo.py", line 14, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 630, in _wrap_awaitable
    return (yield from awaitable.__await__())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 1086, in __await_impl__
    server = await self._create_server()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1353, in create_server
    infos = await tasks.gather(*fs, loop=self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1295, in _create_server_getaddrinfo
    flags=flags, loop=self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1290, in _ensure_resolved
    proto=proto, flags=flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 792, in getaddrinfo
    None, getaddr_func, host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

What is the correct path for the server?

Comment: What error did you get?